# How to set a ComboBox's SelectedItem through code

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox

In my user control, I defined a combobox as below:

```
<GroupBox x:Name="stopEventGroup" Header="Test">
<ComboBox x:Name="stopEventCombobox" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
          DisplayMemberPath ="EventVariableComboxItem" 
          SelectedItem="StopEventVariable"/>
</GroupBox>
```

StopEventVariable is my object(log)'s property. In the code part, I bind its SelectionChanged event to a handler method:

```
stopEventCombobox.SelectionChanged += stopEventCombobox_SelectionChanged;
```

And inside handler, I assign it to my object's property.

```
private void stopEventCombobox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    selectedVar = (LogPublicVariableView)stopEventCombobox.SelectedItem;

    if ((log != null) && (selectedVar != null))
    {
        log.StopEventVariable = selectedVar.ExposedVariable;
    }
}
```

In this constructor's constructor, I bind the data context of combobox's parent:

```
stopEventGroup.DataContext = pvVarList;
```

Until now, everything can work. Now my problem is that. After my object(log) stored the value, next time, when I show this user controller, I　want combobox can show this value automatically, I try to do it in below code in user controller's constructor, but can't work：

```
stopEventCombobox.SelectedItem = log.StopEventVariable;
```

After assign, stopEventCombobox.SelectedItem is still null.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't bound `SelectedItem` to `StopEventVariable`. Use the following syntax: `SelectedItem="{Binding StopEventVariable}"`.

Also make sure `StopEventVariable` is a property.

Comment: yes, StopEventVariable is a property. I bind the DAtaContext in the code part.

Comment: @user2165899 Show more XAML. What is the DataContext of your Window?

Answer (score 0):

Bind the `SelectedItem` property with your source property `(StopEventVariable)` from XAML itself

```
<ComboBox x:Name="stopEventCombobox" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
          DisplayMemberPath ="EventVariableComboxItem" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding StopEventVariable}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is to bind from code behind, here's what you have to do:

```
Binding b1 = new Binding("StopEventVariable");
b1.Source = pvVarList;
stopEventCombobox.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty, b1);
```

Then you just have to set the property StopEventVariable.
for example:

pvVarList.StopEventVariable = someItemsCollection[0];